# Interaction between transform feedback and glMultiDrawArrays?

Tags: opengl, transform-feedback

I have a draw buffer and a transform feedback buffer of same length (say, 1000 vertices), but the draw buffer is not contiguous - for example the data I'm interested in is in indexes 0-100 and 900-1000.  Now I'd rather not process an extra 800 vertices or make two draw calls, so I use glMultiDraw* to batch the two ranges together.  I have yet to find documentation that says if transform feedback will then be similarly populated (with data in indices 0-100 and 900-1000), condensed into a contiguous section (0-100, 101-201), or something else entirely.  Does anyone know what happens, or where this behaviour is specified in documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Transform feedback stores primitives. For each primitive that you render in an `glBeginTransformFeedback`/`glEndTransformFeedback` block, it will write each vertex in it to the bound feedback buffer in sequential order. It has no concept of indices, and primitives generated from more advanced draw modes (`GL_LINE_STRIP`, `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`, etc.) are split up into the most basic primitive types: `GL_POINT`, `GL_LINE`, and `GL_TRIANGLE`.

More reading: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transform_Feedback